# Calculating the tension force/leverage required to pull over a weight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I'm looking for a simple calculation to work out the effort force or leverage on a 100° single pulley, where the load weight is a set distance below the pivot.

So for example, (please excuse my drawing) using a rope to lift a weight of 11,000kgs on the ground with an arm of 7m where the rope runs through a pulley and is being pulled at roughly a 100° angle.[image][image]

Comment: How is the load kept at this angle? In your drawing I see a black arm holding the load in addition to the rope. Does the arm only applies the force horizontally and the rope carries all the vertical force? From your drawing it seems like the arm holds the load on its own without the help of the rope.

Comment: Hi, the arm and the load are connected, the end of the rope is fixed to the load and the pulley is fixed to the top of the arm. So ultimately, I'm trying to calculate how much force will pull over the arm/load. thanks!